# Oauth2 Single-Page Apps Security Considerations

Tags: api, security, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-page-application

I was reading the site Oauth.com trying to understand how implement security in a Single-Page App when i found this statement:

"The only way the authorization code grant with no client secret can be secure is by using the “state” parameter and restricting the redirect URL to trusted clients. Since the secret is not used, there is no way to verify the identity of the client other than by using a registered redirect URL."

If i undestanf correctly, he says that i can verify the identity of my SPA using a registered redirect URL.

Question 1: If I redirect the authorization code to a url (web server), how can i get it (or the access token, or the protected resources) back in my SPA that is running in a browser ?

Question 2: what kind of check can be done in this registered url to verify my SPA identity?

Answer (score 0):

Q1. You receive an authorization code as the login response in a query parameter. Then swap it for an access token. Then call the API with the access token.

Q2. Use HTTPS to prove that you own the redirect URI. Use PKCE to create a one time use secret at runtime.

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

Maybe these resources will give you a clearer idea - feel free to post any follow up questions ..

- [SPA Message Workflow](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/)
- [SPA Tutorial + Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)

Comment: In your first answer, login will happen only once, and the token will be used in multiple API calls after login. is this the right way to do it?

Comment: That's correct yes - to see a working SPA you can log in to the code sample on my [quick start page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/), and maybe look at messages in a tool such as Fiddler.

Comment: About the second answer, HTTPS may prove that I own the redirect url, but I can`t see how it proves the identity of the SPA who did the authorization request.

Comment: PKCE is what proves that the client that initiated the login request is the same party that used the login result. See steps 4, 8 and 9 of the above message workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The authorization code is included in the URL as the `code` query parameter, so you can access it from the SPA (e.g. with `window.location.search`). It will depend on the OAuth2 provider whether you will be able to exchange that code for an access token from your SPA.

If you use a web server to do the code->token exchange, you'll need to put the tokens in a database that your SPA has access to.

The quote from OAuth.com mentions two security measures, the `state` parameter, and registered redirect URLs. These prevent two separate attacks:

1. The `state` parameter prevents an attacker from using your URL with a stolen authorization code to retrieve an access token for a victim user and associate it with the attacker's account. By verifying that the `state` parameter in the URL is the same `state` that you provided to the authorization server, you can be sure that the redirect was generated by the authorization server, and not an attacker.
2. The registered redirect URL prevents an attacker from using your client ID, but sending users to an authorization URL that, after authorization, will redirect them to the attacker's web server instead of yours, allowing the attacker to retrieve the user's access token. With a registered redirect URL, the authorization server will *only* redirect to the pre-registered redirect URLs, which you control, and will not redirect to an attacker's web server.

An alternative to implementing this flow yourself, particularly for a SPA, which has limitations in what OAuth grant types are available to it, is to use a managed OAuth service. [Xkit](https://xkit.co), which I work on, is designed to work with SPAs and moves all of the OAuth flow (including security considerations) out of your code.